# How to extract from multiple <span> tags and group the data together using BS4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have extracted data between span tags based on its class, from a webpage. But at times, the webpage splits a line into multiple fragments and stores it in consecutive  tags. All the children span tags have the same class name.

Following is the HTML snippet:

```
<p class="Paragraph SCX">
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            This week
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            &nbsp;(12/
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            11
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            &nbsp;- 12/1
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            7
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="TextRun SCX">
        <span class="NormalTextRun SCX">
            ):
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="EOP SCX">
        &nbsp;
    </span>
</p>
```

From the above HTML snippet, I need to extract only the innermost span data.

Python code to extract data using BS4:

```
for data in elem.find_all('span', class_="TextRun"):
    a = data.find('span').contents[0]
    a = a.string.replace(u'\xa0', '')
    print (a)
    events_parsed_thisweek.append(a)
```

This code results in each data being separately printed as separate entity. 
Required Output:

> This Week ((12/11 - 12/17):

Any idea how to combine these span tag data together? Thanks!

Comment: Add only NormalTextRun class to forloop  for data in elem.find_all('span', class_="NormalTextRun"):

Comment: get all strings in list and join() them.

Comment: @AnupYadav : That throws the following error: 

a = data.find('span').contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: yes, you don't need in span now, you are already in lower span You need to replace to **a = data.find('span').contents[0]** to **a = data.contents[0]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go. Make sure to wrap the whole `html` within `content` variable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
data = ''.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in soup.select(".NormalTextRun")])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
This week(12/11- 12/17):
```

Comment: @Shahin- Thanks for the answer! I have a small doubt further on: 

I have the above mentioned HTML content wrapped in a list tag (<li>) and multiple such <li> tags from which I am reading the content. Is there a way I can add a delimiter like comma after each <li> tag data is extracted? So that I can store each content as a  list element. 

intended output: [This week(12/11- 12/17):, XYZ, ABC]

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining the relevant information together in a string using the join method.

```
dates = '' 
for data in elem.find_all('span', class_='TextRun'):
    dates.join([dates, data.text])
```